# Advice needed on hover over div which contains sub-divs?

Tags: css, html

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="presetHolder"><h3>Energy Solutions</h3>
    <div class="imageHolder">
      <div class="image"> <img src="/gogivers/assets/Image/energy1.jpg" alt="" height="70" width="70"> </div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="/gogivers/assets/Image/energy2.jpg" alt="" height="70" width="70"> </div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="/gogivers/assets/Image/energy3.jpg" alt="" height="70" width="70"> </div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="/gogivers/assets/Image/energy4.jpg" alt="" height="70" width="70"> </div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="/gogivers/assets/Image/energy5.jpg" alt="" height="70" width="70"> </div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="/gogivers/assets/Image/energy6.jpg" alt="" height="70" width="70"> </div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="/gogivers/assets/Image/energy7.jpg" alt="" height="70" width="70"> </div>
      <div class="image"> <img src="/gogivers/assets/Image/energy8.jpg" alt="" height="70" width="70"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to place a hover effect on the div "one", however the hover effect will only highlight the presetHolder div or the imageHolder div.

Can someone suggest the CSS I would need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
.one:hover .presetHolder {
your hovered styles here
}
```

or

```
.one:hover .imageHolder {
your hovered styles here
}
```